# Bulk Insert in Amplify Datastore

Tags: reactjs, graphql, datastore, aws-amplify

I have 25000 bulk data to insert in datastore. Currently I can do this through iterating. But it takes more time, sometimes browser is crashing.

```
 const savePosts = async (posts) => {
    for (let post of posts) {
      try {
        await DataStore.save(new Post(post));
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

I want to do bulk insert in a single call. How can I do this. Can you suggest a proper way

Answer (score 0):

You should try Promise.allSettled

```
const savePosts = async (posts) => {
    let batchOperations = [];
    for (let post of posts) {
        batchOperations.push(DataStore.save(new Post(post)))
    }

    const resultArray = await Promise.allSettled(batchOperations);

    for (let result of resultArray) {
        if (result.status === 'rejected') {
            console.log(result.reason);
        }
    }
  };
```